# Can an infinite increasing sequence contain its supremum

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

For an increasing sequence $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ of real number, can the $\sup(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ be an element of the sequence?

My guess is that is not the case as there are an infinitely many terms in the sequence and it is an increasing sequence. So if for some natural number $n$ we had that $a_n=\sup(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$, then $a_{n+1}$ would have to be less than or equal to $\sup(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$, but since it is an increasing sequence, we have that $a_{n+1}>a_n$ and thus $a_n\ne \sup(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$.

Am I correct in saying that an infinite increasing sequence does not contain it's supremum?

Background: This came up while I was attempting another exercise in which I had set $a_n=\sup(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$. But then I thought if this can even be the case or not. So I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't derailing.

Comment: Yeah, you got it right

Comment: This doesn't affect the main problem; but perhaps you had set $a_m=\sup(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ instead of $a_n=\sup(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$?

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic My bad that I didn't mention this. But $n$ was just supposed to be an arbitrary natural number and not the index. I should have been more careful.

Comment: @AnikBhowmick Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it would help to distinguish between *increasing* and *strictly increasing*. If a sequence is *just* increasing, the supremum of the sequence can certainly be an element of the sequence. For instance, a trivial example is the constant sequence $$a_n = 1$$
for all $n\ge 1$. On the other hand, for a strictly increasing sequence, your argument is correct.

Comment: I see. In the book that I am reading, there was no such distinction. But the definition of increasing given in the book is the definition one would use for a strictly increasing sequence. Thanks for clearing the doubt!

Comment: No problem! Feel free to accept the answer if it helps. @Seeker

Comment: Yeah I was just about to accept it but there is waiting of $6$ minutes before you can. It just ended so I will accept it now!